# running remote command with arguments and shell using ssh

Tags: bash, bashrc

I'm trying to execute a remote command using ssh.

I need the shell that executes the command to load .bashrc, so so far i've learned that i can use `bash -lc` for that. the problem is that it allows me to execute a command but ignore it's arguments

In general i want to run pm2 (Production process manager for Node.js)
with a list parameter to show me the available running tasks.

when I execute

```
ssh ufk@10.0.0.3 bash -lc pm2 list
```

or

```
ssh ufk@10.0.0.3 bash -lc "pm2 list"
```

I get the same results.
it executes the application as if i didn't provide any arguments at all.

here i provided the argument 'list' to pm2.

any ideas?

Comment: You need a combination of strong and weak quotes around your bash statement. `ssh ufk@10.0.0.3 "bash -lc 'pm2 list'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:
`ssh ufk@10.0.0.3 "bash -lc 'pm2 list'"`

Comment: same results as before

Comment: ssh ufk@10.0.0.3 "bash -lc 'pm2 list'" works! :) thanks

Comment: @ufk, if you wanna use variables in the command, use `"bash -lc \"$cmd\""`

Comment: how do i use pm2 form a remote shell script? i always get pm2: command not found